# Clearing Cache using spring schedule?

Tags: java, spring, caching, schedule

I have the following code which implements a simple cache.

```
 public Observable<String> getSomethingEveryoneWants(String key) {
    final Map<String, String>localCacheReference = GlobalCache.cache;
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
         if(!localCacheReference.containsKey(key)) {
            localCacheReference.put(key, doAHeavyCallToGetValueFor(key));
        } 
        subscriber.onNext(localCacheReference.get(key));
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).map(String.class::cast);
```

}

I also want the ability to clear the cache depending upon some configuration: so I did something

```
//By default run every mid night. This should be defined in propFile
@Scheduled(cron = "${corn.cronString:0 0 0 * * *}")
public void clearCache() {
    GlobalCache.cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
}
```

Do you see any thing wrong with this approach? 
My application starts OK and works as expected for a while. But starts to fail randomly after the clearCache run about 20-30 times. Is there any side affect i need to know?

Update: Its a Spring boot application. The application is throwing null pointer While executing restTemplate.exchange() after clearCache run about 20-30 times.

If i turn off/remove the @Schedule; I am not getting any errors restTemplate.exchange() works as expected. restTemplate.exchange() executes irrespective of @Schedule is running or not and does not depend upon the cache.

The issue is not appering if i clear the cache by any other method, like checking time while reading the cache, and clearing the cache.

I am not able to understand why the restTemplete is failing when @Scheduled is used.

Comment: [mmm corn, haven't had that in a while](https://frinkiac.com/meme/S05E13/625574.jpg?b64lines=TU1NISBDT1JOISBIQVZFTidUCiBIQUQgVEhBVCBJTiBBIFdISUxFLg==)

Comment: What timer service are you using to schedule cron jobs? Check logs, sometime timer service stops if it thinks it will fail over and over and can't deliver.

Comment: This is spring boot application. The clearCache is not failing. I can see the Scheduling running as expected. The application is failing while using spring restTemplete.execute(). If i remove the @Scheduled annotation the restTemplete works as expected.